# CSS : animating another div with ~ or + on div element hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've tried many approaches to get this working correctly, but with no success.. I notice that this question has been asked a few times already, and i've tried the solutions i've found.. but with no success..

So i'll upfront say sorry if someone of you find this question as a duplicate :(

**The hovered element is "food-box", and the element which needs the scale-animation is "food-box-image" :**

```
 <div class="food-box">
        <div class="food-box-image" style="background-image: url(myimage.jpg);"></div>
```

**... and i'm trying to get the animation working like this :**

```
 .food-box:hover ~ .foox-box-image {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
  border:8px solid red;
}
```

but it will not fire :

the only way i got it working, is with specifying .food-box-image:hover, but then it will not fire when hovering the needed div element..

Here's complete code (which runs) :

Anyone know how to do this ?

```css
.fixedbuttons-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.buttons,
.fixedbuttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

    .fixedbuttons > * {
        width: 25%;
    }

        .fixedbuttons > * > * {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
.food-box-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.food-box {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    border-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

    .food-box:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
    }

    .food-box:hover ~ .foox-box-image {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
      border:8px solid red;
    }

    .food-box .food-box-image {
        position: absolute top: 0 left: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .food-box .food-box-content {
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
        position: absolute bottom: 0 left: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffd531;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 80%;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .food-box:hover > .food-box .food-box-content {
        background: yellow !important;
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
    }

    .food-box .food-box-badge {
        display: table;
        background: #ffffff !important;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        border-color: #d3e0e9;
        border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

        .food-box .food-box-badge span {
            color: #666;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
```

```html
<div class="fixedbuttons-container">
  <div class="fixedbuttons">
    <div>
      <a>
        <div class="food-box-container">
          <div class="food-box">
            <div class="food-box-image" style="background-image: url(https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/57c5c6d9cf9e9ad43de2d96e/master/pass/the-ultimate-hamburger.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="food-box-badge"><span>Sydhavsmeny</span></div>
            <div class="food-box-content">
              adslkfjaølkfj
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        <div class="food-box-container">
          <div class="food-box">
            <div class="food-box-image scalable" style="background-image: url(https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/57c5c6d9cf9e9ad43de2d96e/master/pass/the-ultimate-hamburger.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="food-box-badge"><span>Sydhavsmeny</span></div>
            <div class="food-box-content">
              adslkfjaølkfj
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div </div>
```

Comment: You have there a typo (foox vs. food). The second thing is that you need to use  `.food-box:hover > .foox-box-image` instead of `.food-box:hover ~ .food-box-image` (child selector, not sibling).

Comment: @panther : true :) was a last minute bug there... thanks for the update on the > selector... Do you know btw... how i can make sure that the image scaling doesn't go _outside_ the boundries of the parent box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the typo `foox*` to be replaced with `.food-box:hover > .foox-box-image` as pointed out by @panther

Now if you want to only scale within the container box apply `overflow: hidden` to the wrapping container which is `food-box`

Hope this is what you are expecting.

```css
.fixedbuttons-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.buttons,
.fixedbuttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

    .fixedbuttons > * {
        width: 25%;
    }

        .fixedbuttons > * > * {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
.food-box-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.food-box {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    border-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

    .food-box:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
    }

    .food-box:hover > .food-box-image {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    .food-box .food-box-image {
        position: absolute top: 0 left: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .food-box .food-box-content {
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
        position: absolute bottom: 0 left: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #ffd531;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 80%;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .food-box:hover > .food-box .food-box-content {
        background: yellow !important;
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in;
        transition: all .1s ease-in;
    }

    .food-box .food-box-badge {
        display: table;
        background: #ffffff !important;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 39px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        border-color: #d3e0e9;
        border: 1px solid #b3c9e5;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

        .food-box .food-box-badge span {
            color: #666;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
```

```html
<div class="fixedbuttons-container">
  <div class="fixedbuttons">
    <div>
      <a>
        <div class="food-box-container">
          <div class="food-box">
            <div class="food-box-image" style="background-image: url(https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/57c5c6d9cf9e9ad43de2d96e/master/pass/the-ultimate-hamburger.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="food-box-badge"><span>Sydhavsmeny</span></div>
            <div class="food-box-content">
              adslkfjaølkfj
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a>
        <div class="food-box-container">
          <div class="food-box">
            <div class="food-box-image scalable" style="background-image: url(https://assets.epicurious.com/photos/57c5c6d9cf9e9ad43de2d96e/master/pass/the-ultimate-hamburger.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="food-box-badge"><span>Sydhavsmeny</span></div>
            <div class="food-box-content">
              adslkfjaølkfj
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div </div>
```

Comment: Thanks !.. This is _exactly_ what is was looking for ! :)